# How to display properly time on client?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I send TimeSpan object called time from back-end to front-end.

Here how the type looks in back-end:

[image]

I have this type on client side:

[image]

I need to display time variable only hours:minutes:seconds.

How can I convert the type above(i.e. time) to format above?

Comment: What exactly is the question? If you just want to display the time, simply output the hours, minutes and seconds. These are given in the data object.

Comment: What is the measuring of the time? 26 Minutes since what? Do you want to display a clock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var x = new Date(1561000); //replace with TotalMilliSeconds in your case
var time = x.toUTCString().split(' ')[4]; //slit by space character
console.log(time);
```